# VBA to copy values between Excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro to concatenate rows coming from different Excel files all located in the same directory here is the current version:

```
Sub Compilation()
Dim Temp As String
Dim Ligne As Long
Temp = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*.xls")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While Temp <> ""
If Temp <> "Recap.xls" Then
Workbooks.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Temp
Workbooks(Temp).Sheets(1).Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Copy
Workbooks("Recap.xls").Sheets(1).Activate
Ligne = Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("A" & CStr(Ligne)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Workbooks(Temp).Close
End If
Temp = Dir
Loop
Range("A1").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
end sub
```

It's working just fine except the macro copies formulas like in:

[image]

I want it to copy values instead. So I tried changing the line and make it begin from the second line but it doesn't work, someone can help me pleeeeeease,thank you.

Comment: sorry !!i don't undrestand :o

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.Paste`, use the `.PasteSpecial` method:

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Applied to your project, like this:

```
Sub Compilation()
Dim Temp As String
Dim Ligne As Long

Temp = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*.xls")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While Temp <> ""
    If Temp <> "Recap.xls" Then
        Workbooks.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Temp
        Workbooks(Temp).Sheets(1).Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Copy
        Workbooks("Recap.xls").Sheets(1).Activate
        Ligne = Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Range("A" & CStr(Ligne)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Workbooks(Temp).Close
    End If
    Temp = Dir
Loop
Range("A1").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: yeah i use it but it doesn't work ,have you any idea please how use this function ? ,thank you

Comment: **What** doesn't work? I'm fairly certain you're not getting an error message, but if so, please describe it. If you're not getting an error message, then I encourage you to revise your original question to more thoroughly describe what you're trying to accomplish -- currently you only ask how to paste `Values`, and I provide that answer.

Comment: yeah i need to copy all the data ,except the first line ,it will begin from the second line because i don't need to copy (date/valeur) like in the picture when i replace .past with ActiveSheet.Paste.PasteSpecial ("A2") but i have an error "error compilation '424'
objet requis"  ,sorry maybe i'm not good in english :(

Comment: i find this link but it's not ok also ,i don't find what is the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314007/excel-vba-macro-on-the-method-pastespecial

Comment: Sorry, see revision. It should just be `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)`. I revised my answer above.

Comment: Previously I had (erroneously) indicated `ActiveSheet.Paste.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)`. I have revised my answer above to reflect the correct syntax, `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)`.

Comment: Bonjour @Butterflay, vous n'avez pas copié correctement le code de mon exemple. On doit remplacer ce ligne `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial(A2)` avec: `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)`. Celui-ci assume que `Range("A2")` et déjà sélectionné. Si c'est pas vrai, on fait `ActiveSheet.Range("A2").PasteSpecial(xlpasteValues)`.

Comment: c'est toujours la même chose et le même erreur

Comment: J'ai révisé ma réponse ci-dessus. Ca marche? Ou, fait-il un erreur?